# JSON Schema referencing in array items from another file

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have two JSON schemas - `publisher` and `article`, such that there could be multiple articles in a single publisher.

This is the `article` schema (in `a.json`):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Article",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "aid": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "author": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": ["aid", "author", "title"]
}
```

And I'm trying to reference this in `publisher` schema as below (in `p.json`, in the same dir):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Publisher",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pid": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "lang": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "articles": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "$ref": "./a.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["pid", "articles"]
}
```

I would ideally want the data to raise error if any of the articles do not have the required fields as mentioned in `a.json`. But this does not seem to happen:

```py
import json, jsonschema

schema = json.load(open("p.json"))
data = {
  "pid": 1,
  "articles": [
    {
      "aid": 100,
      "title": "test",
    }
  ]
}
jsonschema.validate(data, schema)
```

The last line should raise an exception, as `article` does not have the `author` key that is marked as a requierd field in `a.json`.

But somehow, it raises `_WrappedReferencingError: Unresolvable: ./a.json` exception.

How can I reference `a.json` here such that it raise the correct exception?

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations understand filesystem references natively, but the implementation you're using doesn't. You need to configure it to map the `p.json` URI to your schema. I'm just going off of the [documentation](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/referencing/#making-additional-in-memory-schemas-available), but it looks like you would do something like this,

```py
from referencing import Registry, Resource
from jsonschema import Draft202012Validator

article = json.load(open("a.json"))
publisher = json.load(open("p.json"))

registry = Registry().with_resources(
    [
        ("http://example.com/a.json", Resource.from_contents(article))
    ],
)

validator = Draft202012Validator(publisher, registry=registry)
validator.validate(data)
```

In addition, you'll need to add `"$id": "http://example.com/p.json"` to your `p.json` schema. That gives the implementation a base URI to use to resolve the `a.json` reference in the `p.json` schema. That makes the reference resolve to `http://example.coma/a.json` which matches a schema in the registry.

Comment: @Shod, if it doesn't make sense to use an `http(s):`, you should know that you can use any URI to identify your schemas; just make sure that the `$refs` match them.  If you're going to use relative URIs in your references (e.g. `a.json`), the URIs need to support paths.

Answer (score 0):

The way you outlined your schemas is correct. Your error is the trailing comma on `title`. This is invalid JSON itself, not even JSON Schema.

Comment: the JSON is valid - the comma is for `properties`, not `title`

Comment: You have a comma in your instance  
`data = {
  "pid": 1,
  "articles": [
    {
      "aid": 100,
      "title": "test",
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: ah, that's python, not JSON exactly, and this is allowed in python.

Comment: the data instance should be valid json, regardless of the language used.  if you remove the trailing comma in that line, the instance validates successfully

Comment: did you try that in python? when you print `data`, or do `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))`, it will print without the comma

Comment: Python modifies it but JSON Schema validation doesn't like it.  Otherwise, your instance validates against the schema without an issue